# What does generic immersion mean?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been looking for the meaning of **generic immersion**

In the textbook I am reading, a theorem involves a curve with y coordinate satisfying $y'(0)=0$ says at some stage the following: "...Since $y''(0)\ne0$ by the genericity condition..." so I thought those are immersions without inflection points.

I googled it in vain. The article among those I found on Google which came closest to defining a generic immersion said that the generic open subset of immersions is contained in the embedded curves whose curvature never vanishes and if the torsion at a point P on the curve vanishes then the derivative of the torsion doesn't vanish.

So the above gives only a necessary condition to be generic.

What really defines it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic means dense in the appropriate topological space of functions being considered. Given what I can guess your context is, we might look at the $C^2$ topology.

Comment: I suspect it means (1) or (2), but not just *dense*: **(1)** The set of elements under consideration is a superset of a dense open set. **(2)** The set of elements under consideration is the complement of a first category set (i.e. a *comeager set*; also called a *residual set*). Property (1) implies property (2), but not conversely.

Comment: You mean, they are simply using the fact that curves that have non-vanishing curvature are dense?

Comment: And what is a comeager set?

Comment: Oh :-P complement of a meagre set!

Answer (score 1):

There is no *the* generic immersion or even *a* generic immersion, just properties generic for immersions.

In the context of differential topology, a property is generic if it is satisfied by a comeager set.

In most cases, genericity of some property is shown using Thom's transversality theorem.

The reason why there's no *a* generic function is simple: a conjunction of uncountably many generic conditions need not be generic; in fact, it might be contradictory. For instance, having a nonzero derivative at a particular point is generic in $C^\infty({\bf R},{\bf R})$, as is having a nonzero derivative at a countable set of points, but having nonzero derivative *everywhere* is not: only injective functions have nonzero derivative everwhere. But this condition is not even dense: there's no injective function anywhere near $y=x^2$.

Comment: Hmm :-) realised it. So deleted my comment. Is it still visible?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC: No. I will delete mine as well.